# Does the order of creation of stack resources affect the execution of 'cdk deploy'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I read a file `clients.json` and then create stack resources based on the input from the file. This file contains an array. And for each item of an array I create similar resources. Like this,

```js
for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
  const domainName = clients[i].dnsName;
  // now create route53 entry for the client.

  const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(
    this,
    `serviceTask${i}`,
    {
      cpu: 512,
      memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
    }
  );
  // now create container for clients[i]
}
```

Now suppose the first entry in `clients` array is deleted and recreated at the end of the array. Should this remove all the previous client resources and recreated them in new order? It seems that this is happening at my site.

Also, when I remove one entry (first entry) and running `cdk deploy`, it is still removing all the entries and recreating them.

How can I tell cdk that it just has to remove resources for one entry and do not touch others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array order changes, the value of the `serviceTask${i}` [Construct IDs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/identifiers.html#identifiers_construct_ids) will change.  If the CDK Construct ID changes, the CloudFormation [Logical ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/identifiers.html#identifiers_logical_ids) resource identifier will change.  If the Logical ID changes, CloudFormation replaces the resource:

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/identifiers.html#identifiers_logical_id_stability): Avoid changing the logical ID of a resource after it has been created. AWS CloudFormation identifies resources by their logical ID. Therefore, if you change the logical ID of a resource, AWS CloudFormation creates a new resource with the new logical ID, then deletes the existing one.

The solution is to make the Construct IDs unique, but independent of array order.  Consider adding a client name or other fixed identifier in each `clients.json` entry for use in the Construct IDs.