# How to add listener rules in a loop; with priority derived from loop index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In continuation to my [previous quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76212068/does-the-order-of-creation-of-stack-resources-affect-the-execution-of-cdk-deplo/76215311#76215311), now I am stuck at the following juncture. I read a file clients.json and then create stack resources based on the input from the file. This file contains an array. And for each item of an array I create similar resources. In the following code, I am adding listener rules in a loop for containers which are also created in the same loop.

```js
//add listener for application inside load balancer
const myListener = alb.addListener("myListener", {});
// rule with priority 1 added here.

for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
  const tenantId = clients[i].tenantId;
  const domainName = clients[i].dnsName;

  const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(
    this,
    `serviceTask${tenantId}`,
    {}
  );

  // now create container for clients[i]
  // ...

  // now add listeners to existing LB
  const myTarget = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
    this,
    `myService${tenantId}targetgroup`,
    {}
  );

  const listenerRule = new elbv2.ApplicationListenerRule(
    this,
    "listenerRule" + tenantId,
    {
      listener: myListener,
      /*priority: i + 2; */ /*rules with priority 2 and above*/
      priority: clients.length - i + 1,
      action: ListenerAction.forward([myTarget]),
      conditions: [elbv2.ListenerCondition.hostHeaders([domainName])],
    }
  );
}
```

Look at the `priority` field in the last block. One line is commented and the current approach is uncommented. Both the approaches are similar. All of this is in a for-loop. In the commented part, I am starting from 2 and going till the length of clients array. In the other approach, I am starting from the end.

Suppose there are 4 elements in the array. So the listener rule priorities will be - 5, 4, 3, 2.

| container | listener rule priority |
| --- | --- |
| containerA | 5 |
| containerB | 4 |
| containerC | 3 |
| containerD | 2 |

In a new deployment, suppose the first element of the `clients` array is removed. So the updated priorities will be - 4, 3, 2.

| container | listener rule priority |
| --- | --- |
| containerB | 4 |
| containerC | 3 |
| containerD | 2 |

This is not much of a hassle. `cdk deploy` runs perfectly. This is because rule with priority 5 is simply deleted and no new rule has to be created. The remaining containers map to the same priority as before.

Now suppose the last element if the `clients` array is removed. So the updated cloudformation template will map the containers to the priorities like this,

| container | listener rule priority |
| --- | --- |
| containerA | 4 |
| containerB | 3 |
| containerC | 2 |

Notice that containers A, B, C were earlier mapped to 5, 4, 3 respectively, but after removal of the last element, they are mapped to 4, 3, 2 respectively. This gives "**ListenerRule already exist**" error during deployment. Because when A is getting mapped to priority 4, it notices that 4 priority is already mapped to B. And so on...

So, how should I handle such a deployment update where a high priority rule (one with low priority value) is removed and other rules shift by one.

Answer (score 1):

The CloudFormation `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule` [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html) explain why you're getting the error when re-assigning the rule priorities:

> A listener can't have multiple rules with the same priority.  If you try to reorder rules by updating their priorities, do not specify a new priority if an existing rule already uses this priority, as this can cause an error. If you need to reuse a priority with a different rule, you must remove it as a priority first, and then specify it in a subsequent update.

In other words, you're looking to set unique, semi-permanent priority values, while accomodating subsequent insertions and deletions.

One approach would be to assign an explicit priority value to each entry in `clients.json`.  These priorities would be set with a gap of, say, 100 to accomodate later reordering (rules apparently accept priority values up to `50000`).

- containerA: `100`
- containerB: `200`
- containerC: `300`

If a new customer comes along, you can give her top priority with `containerD: 50`, for instance, without touching the existing priorities.

Comment: Is there a way to fetch existing rules and priorities? That can make the logic really clean i.e. without leaving any gaps.

Comment: @PankajJangid Yes, it is possible, although storing CDK inputs locally under source control [is the CDK Way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context).  More fundamentally, I don't see how looking up the deployed rules/priorities solves the problem.  That being said, it is unclear to me whether your rule priorities have ordinal semantic meaning (order matters) or whether you just need to avoid duplicates (priority order does not matter).  The "gaps" approach presumes the first motivation.

Comment: at number of clients in my setup are not going to increase beyond 200. So what I am doing is this. I change the starting counter before each `cdk deploy`. Alternatively, I keep it at 1000 and 2000. In one deployment, the priorities are 1000, 1001, 1002, ... in next deployment 2000, 2001, 2002,...

Although I am not satisfied with this approach because there is a manual intervention each time. But it works for now.